# Input arguments and password in cmd.exe in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ssh, passwords

I have to establish an `ssh` connection using cmd.exe . I am using a button in a winform application to do the process. After I pass a command for an `ssh` connection, `cmd.exe` prompts to enter a password. How can I pass a password as an argument besides passing an `ssh -p root@localhost` command (for establishing a connection)? I have to run `cmd.exe` as a background process. Please help. Thank you.

I am new to c# and one of the code i tried:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
             System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
             startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
             startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
             startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
             startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

             using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
             {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("/c ssh -p 2022 root@localhost"); //first comand i need to enter
                    sw.WriteLine("/c alpine");//command to be typed as password in response to 1st cmd's output
                    sw.WriteLine("/c mount.sh");//command to be typed nest in response to 2nd cmd's next output
                }
             }
        }
        catch {}
    }
```

Comment: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) Please show your code so we can give answers that fit in.

Comment: Added my code.The problem is that the codes i tried with cannot pass the password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Start` your `process`.

before that, you need to assign the `startinfo` to your `process`.

also, if you do not want to open a window, you should use `CreateNoWindow` instead of setting `WindowStyle` to `Hidden`.

I changed your code like this:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("/c ssh -p 2022 root@localhost"); //first comand i need to enter
                sw.WriteLine("/c alpine");//command to be typed as password in response to 1st cmd's output
                sw.WriteLine("/c mount.sh");//command to be typed nest in response to 2nd cmd's next output
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code also doesnt give the output.The problem is that the codes i tried with cannot pass the password. Thanks  for the answer